# ValueError: too many values to unpack, can't figure out nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

So I'm trying to create a piece of code that will take a green screen image and place it on a background without the green screen and be transparent. I'm doing this for an assignment so I can't use the chroma key or alpha key feature. I'm supposed to use nested loops to count each green pixel and if it's not green, I don't copy it to the background image. Anyway, this is my code.

```
for i in range(0, fy):
    for j in range(0, fx):
        (red,green,blue) = fg.get_at( (i,j) )
        if green == 255:
            green = 0
        else :
            fg.set_at( (i,j), (red,0,blue) )

        pygame.display.update()
```

fx and fy are declared earlier as the size of the image for the foreground green screen image. I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a6.py", line 60, in <module>
    (red,green,blue) = fg.get_at( (i,j) )
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

someone please help me

Comment: (red,green,blue)  -> red,green,blue

fg.get_at( (i,j) ) returns tuple, you need as many variables as tuple`s elements. Now you have one variable on the left "(red,green,blue)".

Comment: What is `get_at()`? What exact python3 version are you using? Also, please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: Try debugging with print what `fp.get_at` returns

Comment: I'm guessing there may be an alpha channel you forgot to unpack : `(red,green,blue,alpha) = fg.get_at( (i,j) )`

Answer (score 1):

problem was I had to write the code with an underscore like so

```
(red,green,blue,_) = fg.get_at( (i,j) )
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
red, green, blue = fg.get_at( (i,j) )
```

instead of

```
(red,green,blue) = fg.get_at( (i,j) )
```

Comment: No, this makes no difference. Using `()` is not what creates a tuple, commas do.

Comment: Both the syntax are same. Comma separated variable names are considered as tuple regardless of the brackets. The problem should be get_at might return more than 3 variables.

Comment: So how can I fix this then?